# set favicon.ico on google appspot

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to put an icon,

I used this:

```
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: static/images/favicon.ico
  upload: static/images/favicon\.ico
```

Taken from this

https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general

But it doesn't work, I just get a 404 (despite having created the file locally).

How should I set a favicon? And how to report to google a bug in their FAQ?

Comment: That snippet is correct, works for me on dev and production. You get the 404 at www.example.com/favicon.ico or on any page? I believe this snippet (along with all other static uploads) should come *before* all page handlers.

Comment: Yes you were right, I had to put it before my /* handler.

Comment: Ah, that'll be it. Handlers match in order - so you can't have a 'catch all' `/*` before something more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handlers match in order as written in your app.yaml, so the `url:` regex's must (to be effective) go from most to least specific.

For example:

```
- url: /robots\.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots\.txt

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: app.APP
```

If the third here is not the last, anything after it is unused - "/favicon.ico" is a regex match for `.*`, so we must be more specific about how to handle this case, before the 'catch all' handler.